# JavaFx 8 - Changing CSS style property values at runtime

Tags: css, fonts, javafx, javafx-8

I have to scale/change by button's text size dynamically whose default values are in CSS

```
.button { 
    -fx-font-size: 20;        
}
```

in JavaFx

```
button.getStyleClass().add("button");
```

Now I have to scale the fonts by factor 2 but there is no way to find the existing font size so that I could just multiply the factor

```
button.setStyle("-fx-font-size:"+oldVal*2);
```

How do I get the existing font size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as using

```
button.getFont().getSize();
```

It works only after the stage was shown.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted . it works for me now. However I was looking for a generic solution where I can multiply the factor in the style even before setting it for the first time.

Comment: You could parse the stylesheet but with all the inheritance that might be going on I rather advise against it.

Comment: I know, I could do a getStyle() and look for the string separated by ";" and containing the style name but that sounds fragile.